# Is there a way to see how many times other users have viewed a shared item on Google Drive?

Tags: google-drive

Does anybody know if there is a way to see how many times other users have viewed a shared item on Google Drive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the Google Drive product team, no, this isn't a supported function. However, there is a workaround of sorts.

Submit your document link to the http://goo.gl URL shortening service and share that URL only. This service provides information on how many times that link was clicked, which is about as close as you can currently get to knowing how many times your document was accessed.

[Source](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!msg/drive/X2G9po1U9Zc/JiS23kjoXyYJ)